# How do I check if a user has their DM's open? | discord.js v 14

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am making a bot that can dm a user. If the dm's of the user are off it says the message is successfully sent but in the console it returns an error.
So, what can I do to check if a user's dm is open?
The code I'm trying to run:

```
const rec = interaction.options.getUser('user')
        const user = interaction.user.id
       try {
        rec.send({ embeds:[ new EmbedBuilder().setDescription(`<@${user}> says to you: ${message} `).setColor("#f05c51")
        .then(interaction.reply(({ content: 'Successfully sent', ephemeral: true })))

      ] })
       } catch (error) {
        interaction.reply(({ content: `Could not send message, maybe dm's off? -> ${error}`, ephemeral: true }))
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You need to use **.catch()**

```
rec.send({ embeds: [YOUREMBED] })
    .then(message => console.log(`Sent message: ${message.content}`))
    .catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `unhandledRejection` to know if my bot can't send a message to a specific user, also can use it all of  `unhandledRejection errors`

```js
process.on('unhandledRejection', async(error) => {
    const admin = client.channels.cache.get('-----')
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(`\`\`\`\j\s\n${error.message || error.name || error }\n\`\`\``)
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .setTimestamp()

    admin.send({embeds: [embed]})
    console.log(error)
});
```

You can also try it on your code.